Where to store certificates in windows machines when using C++ GRPC Server and Client
I have created C++ GRPC Server and client using SSL. The server private key, certificate and CA root all reside in the file system in C drive. This works well but I would like to know where the certificates should be stored on production machines?
I see Windows certificate store is an option.
GRPC Server needs to read the.crt file and .key file. From what I researched there is no way to store the private key in MMC. I can convert the .crt file to .pfx file ( so that it has both public and private keys ) and upload it to Personal Certificates in Local Computer. But, I am also unsure how the server can read the pfx file.
Server code:
     std::string server_address = absl::StrFormat("localhost:%d", 50051);
     std::string serverkey;
     std::string servercert;

     read("C:\\ServerCertDir\\server.key", serverkey);
     read("C:\\ServerCertDir\\server.crt", servercert);

     grpc::SslServerCredentialsOptions::PemKeyCertPair pkcp;
     pkcp.private_key = serverkey;
     pkcp.cert_chain = servercert;

     grpc::SslServerCredentialsOptions ssl_opts;
     ssl_opts.pem_key_cert_pairs.push_back(pkcp);

     std::shared_ptr<grpc::ServerCredentials> creds;
     creds = grpc::SslServerCredentials(ssl_opts);

     builder.AddListeningPort(server_address, creds);

Client code:
     std::string server_address{ "localhost:50051" };
     std::string root;

    read("C:\\ClientCertDir\\ca.crt", root);

    grpc::SslCredentialsOptions ssl_opts;
    ssl_opts.pem_root_certs = root;`your text`

    auto channel_creds = grpc::SslCredentials(grpc::SslCredentialsOptions(ssl_opts));

    auto channel = grpc::CreateChannel(server_address, channel_creds) };


Usually private key saved in some container, then information about it stored in CRYPT_KEY_PROV_INFO and assigned to certificate context via CertSetCertificateContextProperty( CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID ). Then we can got private key via CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey

Thanks your comment gave me some ideas on how to start this. I will try!
